# Recommendations for a good C#/ .NET based lexical analyser

Tags: c#, lexical-analysis

Can anyone recommend a good .NET based lexical analyser, preferably written in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR has a [C# target](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target)

Comment: ANTLR looks good in so far as it has lots of features, but the documentation is very poor.

Comment: There's good documentation at http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference ($24 PDF)

Comment: $24 is a lot of money for a PDF that I cannot preview before buying. Are you connected with the author, or recommending it because you have bought it and found it useful?

Comment: Neither, but I do plan on buying the book. There's a free chapter excerpt at http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/errors.pdf .

Comment: Thanks for the link marxidad. It looks good from what that chapter shows. Guess I'll take the plunge...

Comment: I just bought the book + PDF combo.

Answer (score 3):

Download the Visual Studio SDK; it includes a managed parser/lexer generator.

(Edit: It was written on my university campus, apparantly :D)

Comment: They use gplex and gppg, not sure if they changed anything to it though.

Comment: AFAIK, they just changed the name.

Comment: Any, just had a look, they have some new version out! Yay!

Comment: What is the name of the SDK's p/l generator?

Answer (score 2):

[gplex](http://plas.fit.qut.edu.au/gplex/) and cs_lex

Comment: New link to Gardens Point LEX (gplex): https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gplex  Named after a QUT campus, or possibly https://github.com/k-john-gough/gplex