# line breaks based on sequence of characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have lines of parameters in a text file, which can be spread over several lines. They are terminated (the actual line break) by a sequence of characters, which can also be spread over several lines or contain spaces like these three (non-exhaustive) examples:

```
< x >

< x 
  > 

<   x >
```

I would like to tidy this text file up so that I can actually parse it. The output should be something like this (P1 … P3 are parameters):

```
P1 P2 P3 < x >
P1 P2 P3 < x >
P1 P2 P3 < x >
```

Original:

```
P1 P2 P3 < x   >

P1 P2    P3 < x 

>
P1 P2 

P3 < 
x >
```

Comment: what have you tried? Is the format always the same? can you please give an example? is it like "1 a6 three < 12 >"?

Comment: The sequence is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do fine with a simple [lexical analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).

See some previous SO questions:

- [Recommendations for a good C#/ .NET based lexical analyser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131920/recommendations-for-a-good-c-net-based-lexical-analyser)
- [C#/.NET Lexer Generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172189/c-net-lexer-generators?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Well a very dump approach would be going over it, char by char like this:

```
  var output = new List<string>(); // this holds the parameter lines
  var line = string.Empty;
  foreach (var c in str) // str holds the input string
  {
    if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') continue;

    line += c;
    if (c == '>')
    {
      output.Add(line);
      line = string.Empty;
    }
  }
```

You'd still have to do formating and so on, but I hope you get the idea...

Comment: Thanks. That's the kind of stuff I tried. Problem is that it is not just > but a sequence of characters (and different combinations of them) - see original question.

Comment: @csetzkorn That's why I asked for a real example. Show me under what conditions my code doesn't work. Give us some data :-) For the format you provided, it does work.

Comment: The condition = data are in the question. The 'line break' is < x > or combinations of it NOT >. See question.

Comment: Okay, sorry so I somehow missunderstood the question. Then you would have to get rid of the linebreaks and split the string by the actual linebreak, eg. "< x >". Since qstebom was able to give a helpful answer I won't update my post :)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did. There was still the challenge to cope with all 'combinations' of < x > (see question).